# Docker container doesn’t starts after changing host directory

Tags: django, docker

I have a django app which i’m dockerizing. Below is the docker-compose.yml file

```
 nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: ng01
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./webapp/static:/static
      - ./certs:/etc/ssl


 web:
    build: .
    command: python ./webapp/server.py
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ./webapp/static:/static
    networks:
      - nginx_network
      - couchserver_network
      - dummyapi_flaskapp_network
```

when i change the name of the host directory from where it is run, i’m getting the following error : python: can't open file './webapp/server.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I have copied the host directory to image using :

```
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code/
```

So after renaming my host directory why python is unable to find the server.py file as it is available in containers **code** directory.

I’m novice in docker and have little or no knowledge in volumes. Any help is really appreciated. How can i run this computer in another machine where the host directory wont be available.

Update: Removed volumes from web and it is working fine. But removing the volumes from nginx throws "This site can’t be reached" error

Comment: could you indicate where is server.py on your host in relative path from where you run the docker command ?

Answer (score 1):

The volumes declared override the content of the images when the container start. You should remove them as you copy your files inside the image (this is better else you need to have the file in every host you will run your container).

```
web:
    build: .
    command: python ./webapp/server.py
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nginx_network
      - couchserver_network
      - dummyapi_flaskapp_network
```

Simple Dockerfile for NGINX, you don't need an entrypoint already defined in base image:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
RUN mkdir /static
COPY ./webapp/static/ /static/
```

Comment: By removing the volume, server and my reverse proxy are running. But i'm unable to access the site. Getting "This site can’t be reached" error. I'm adding my reverse proxy as well here

Comment: Did you add your static files at the correct location in the build ? You need to copy them as well (or you need to keep the volume for the static files).

Comment: COPY . /code/  would copy all the files from host to code directory of container right?
I have updated the question. By removing volumes from web it is working fine.But removing volumes from nginx is causing the trouble

Comment: You can check if the files are inside your NGINX container with docker exec <container_name> ls /static if not you need to check your dockerfile for NGINX

Comment: You are right. when i keep volumes in nginx i can see all the files in static using the docker exec command. But if i remove the volumes, i see ls: /static: No such file or directory . So how can i add these files to nginx image. I'm building the image using "nginx:alpine" and there is no dockerfile nor entrypoint for this

Comment: you can build an image based on it, just start your dockerfile with FROM nginx:alpine

Comment: tried it, 
FROM  nginx:alpine
COPY ./webapp/static /static/
but "Service 'nginx' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder491820430/webapp/static: no such file or directory" error is thrown.

My Dockerfile is not in root directory, but docker-compose.yml is in root. Is this might be the cause?

Comment: fix the path to be relative to the Dockerfile

Comment: I have given the path as relative only :

nginx:
    build: ./config/nginx/

my Dockerfile resides in this directory "./config/nginx/"